What is the correct algorithm to group GPS coordinates in an optimal way?
I need an algorithm to group the closest GPS coordinates.
I am currently using OSRM to manage that for me, but due to its limitations (100 items per request), I'm going to have to make my own local implementation.
I've read about Dijkstra's, A* (its variation), contraction hierarchies, etc... From what I understood, most of them, if not all, require the points to have a connection and that's where my problem lies. In my scenario all coordinates are "connected" to each other. You could reach any by any. I just want them to be grouped by the closest.
One example is displayed in the image below (take it with a grain of salt, it's just a visual representation to try and explain my problem):

In the scenario proposed by the image above, I have 187 coordinates and require them to be in groups of 5 of the closest coordinates. Given that using real maps would require a lot of memory, I'd like to just use the distance between points, ignoring edges, roads and profiles (walking, driving, etc - even though walking would be the way to go).
I understand that by not using a real map I will run into issues like: "closest GPS coordinate requires crossing a river", but that's something I can live with, at the moment.
Given the above explanation, my questions are:
1 - Is there an algorithm, other than the ones mentioned, that would help me solve that problem?
2 - If Dijkstra's is the way to go, could I create manual connections between the coordinates so they would work? How would it work with Dijkstra's?
Hopefully I was able to clearly explain the problem, but if not, please ask me any questions you may have so I can improve it.

I was using OSRM
I migrated to a local (erratic) solution using .NET's .Distance
I read about Dijkstra's, A* (its variation) and contraction hierarchies algorithms


Hard to understand how the grouping really works. For example why 20 belongs to 19 and not to the closest 6??? Why 9 with 21 which is much distant than 23 or 10?

Thank you for asking, as I've mentioned, please take that image with a grain of salt. But to answer your question, it just came up to where it started the grouping. In that case it was the orange group. But the idea is that the algorithm would receive the coordinates and just group by the closest distance in groups of N items. Is that helpful?

Not very fluent on the subject but you should have a look at graph partioning or may be even to graph colouring.

Ok for the orange but now which node? I suppose the number 1?

Yes. Once a group is created, those items are removed from the list of available coordinates, but again, please don't take the groups in that image too seriously, it was just to try to explain the idea, but maybe it was not the best way.

Also, it should always try to group by N (something I forgot to mention), if possible. Now that I'm talking to you, I'm thinking I could improve that by adding a limit, creating a max distance allowed or something.

Maybe this paper will helps you to find a path to the solution. "partitioning", "clustering"... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.insee.fr/en/statistiques/fichier/3635545/imet131-q-chapitre-13.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwikrI6J_q2GAxXEAfsDHVMvD4gQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2bW8wLxSQ99XixGaukZGEZ

@Jean-BaptisteYunès thank you for that! I'm reading it

@Jean-BaptisteYunès thank you for the article, it seems graph partitioning is the way to go here (I was using clusters with OSRM). While I wait for others to weigh in, I'm going to try to implement that.

I'd look into K-means, which is pretty much suitable for this application:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(10)
gps = np.random.rand(500, 2) * 100

clusters = 7

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=clusters, random_state=0).fit(gps)

lbs = kmeans.labels_
ctr = kmeans.cluster_centers_

for i in range(clusters):
    cluster_points = gps[lbs == i]

plt.scatter(gps[:, 0], gps[:, 1], c=lbs, cmap='viridis')
plt.scatter(ctr[:, 0], ctr[:, 1], s=300, c='black')
plt.show()


Prints

From Wiki

Also see Convex Hull

Hi, thank you. KMeans is the one I use today to cluster data when it's over 100 records. It looks like it's not 100%, maybe it's my implementation. Do you think this a better approach?

@eestein It's possible. Just add a new question with your K-Means code so that we see. If you need 100% accuracy, classic algorithms are good.

Thank you, but it won't work for me. As mentioned in my question, I need the groups to be limited. Clustering with limit would be a NP hard problem... it'd be better to just do the whole logic "by hand". Thanks again, if you know of an option for that scenario, I'd appreciate it. [Just so you know: I tried it - my previous code using OSRM and the current one, after some decent research]
